# iterm2 API: Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 1912)

Tags: python, iterm2

I am trying to run the script defined here:
https://iterm2.com/python-api/tutorial/example.html

```
import iterm2

async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    window = app.current_window
    if window is not None:
        await window.async_create_tab()
    else:
        print("No current window")

iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

Running script (python3 code.py) result in the following error

```
File "code.py", line 20, in <module>
    iterm2.run_forever(main)
  File "/Users/naveen/ENV/mysite-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iterm2/connection.py", line 528, in run_forever
    Connection().run_forever(coro, retry, debug)
  File "/Users/naveen/ENV/mysite-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iterm2/connection.py", line 159, in run_forever
    self.run(True, coro, retry, debug)
  File "/Users/naveen/ENV/mysite-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iterm2/connection.py", line 240, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(self.async_connect(async_main, retry))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/naveen/ENV/mysite-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iterm2/connection.py", line 416, in async_connect
    async with self._get_connect_coro() as websocket:
  File "/Users/naveen/ENV/mysite-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 604, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "/Users/naveen/ENV/mysite-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/websockets/legacy/client.py", line 622, in __await_impl__
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1033, in create_connection
    raise OSError('Multiple exceptions: {}'.format(
OSError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 61] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 1912), [Errno 61] Connect call failed ('::1', 1912, 0, 0)
```

python version: 3.8.3

iterm2 Build version:  3.3.10

iterm2 python library: iterm2==1.25

reference: https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/593

Comment: And you're running iterm2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a Python runtime in iterm2 and allow Python scripts in a separate step, plus install the iterm2 module.

Install Python runtime: Scripts -> Manage -> Runtime

Allow Python scripts: Preferences, tab General, sub tab Magic: tick the "Enable Python API" checkbox. Mac OS' Accessibility settings will ask "Enable Python API?", click ok.

[image: Preferences for enabling the Python API]

[image: MacOS asking for confirmation]

Then run `pip3 install iterm2`.